# C# class arrays and indexers, do multiple arrays in a class have to be public?

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

I have a class that's going to hold 3 parallel arrays. (For a class assignment we're basically coding a rudimentary xml parser...beginning programming class)

*Note, I'm doing this in very basic OOP. I've got an XMLObject class which has the arrays, and holds the xml elements in one array, the data values in another, and the ending  elements in the third. I've also got an XMLParse object that does the actual parsing, and stores the strings to their various arrays as it finds them. I've been forbiddin from using .net's xml stuff for this assignment, has to be a byte by byte read in.

Now I was reading on MSDN about indexers, and as I understand it, I can either only have one array using an indexer(since that's the only way for properties to receive parameters), or I have to make my arrays public so that the parse class can add to them, and main or another class can read from them.

Do I have that right or am I missing something/not understanding how to get and set arrays of one class from another?

Does the same go for list as well?

Comment: So attributes are just part of the opening tag? The way I see it, an element consists of an opening tag, content and a closing tag. You want a class to encapuslate this 3-tuple?

Comment: the actual parsing of xml isn't the important part. My teacher uses attributes interchangeably with child nodes, and he calls parent nodes containers. The actual code I came up with doesn't recognize actual attributes(probably won't, since that's not the point of the lab exercise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question you want to have many indexers on your class which will return the various elements from the arrays that the class holds.

you can have many indexers, but only if the type used by each indexer is different.  So you could have an indexer by `int` and an indexer by `string`, but not 2 indexers by `int`.

From the sounds of things you won't be able to use indexers to access all the values your class holds, as they will probably all want to use `int`.

Publicly exposing the arrays is one option, but you could also provide different methods for reading each thing, so you could have `GetXmlElement(int index)`, `GetDataValue(int index)` and `GetEndingElement(int index)` to provide access to the contents of the arrays.

Another option would be to store the data in arrays internally, but accept and return a class which bundled up all the data together.  This way you could have a single indexer which returned all the data, as all the data would be a single object with the element, data value and end element in it.

you would have to provide similar methods for adding data and potentially removing and changing as well.  Whether you want to do this, opr just exopse the underlying arrays/lists depends on if you want to be able to exercise control over the adding/accessing/deleting/changing of the arrays or not.

Comment: In my particular case, it's probably not all that important to have the arrays set to private. There will only be one spot for each array in my program that adds to them (the parse class, depending on if it determines what it's reading in is an element,data value, or end of element).

there might be a few places I get the values, as I like to dump to console to see what's going on. It looks like, from what you've said, if I want to have control over what can change the values, I'll have to use c++ style getters and setters.

Comment: yes if you want to have control over what goes in and out or indexed data, then you have to use a method as properties are not indexable, and will only allow you to either set the whole array, or expose the array directly for modification

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `List<T>` instead of array for storing the data. It is much easier to work with.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: I've been looking at List<T>, but it's not covered in the class (in the teachers examples, including his OOP example, he only uses arrays)

He also uses C++ style getters and setters instead of properties.

If I can access subsets of List<T> like an array I'd probably use that instead.

Comment: whilst this is a valid (and excellent) suggestion, there may be a reason the class is using arrays.  after all they could use the built in types to read the xml rather than do it byte by byte...

Comment: Sounds like you could possibly teach yourself C# (you sound smart enough :p) and save the costs of the class, it's not particularly hard if you use a good book like Apress Pro C# 2010 or Jon Skeet's book.

Comment: @Sam: My comment was aimed more in the direction of C++ style getter and setter methods. Using arrays instead of List *might*  have didactic reasons, although I can't really see them :)

Comment: I need that little piece of paper called a degree in order to land a job in this current market,unfortunately, or I probably would just teach myself. Not to mention my only source of income right now is the BAH the VA pays me for going to school.

Comment: @Sam 
the reason we're using arrays is partially because the teachers only been working with C# for like 3 years. He basically took his c++ code of this lab assignment, changed a few method calls to line up with .net (like Console.WriteLine()) and crapped this lab out.

Comment: @Daniel, I agree that using Lists is a better option, and that the class sounds like its being taught by a c++ person (or maybe Java - no properties there either) who has had to switch to c#.  This answer does not directly address the OPs question is all, although it does provide valuable learning material.

Comment: @Sam my teacher was originally an Assembly to BASIC to C to C++ to Java programmer, only picked up C# a few years ago. In fact his labs for this c# class were originally written in Java,then migrated to c++ and now C#

Comment: @Tyler W, its important not to get bogged down in the small differences between the syntax of the language.  Methods vs Properties is all a bit 'meh' at the end of the day, the differences between direct access and a level of indirection to control access is much more important.

Comment: @Sam, with as simple as the actual logic for this lab is (read in provided xml file, store element nodes in one array and their data in another and output) I probably don't really need indirection for the arrays. In the teachers example he has parse call his set attributes for the arrays depending what it finds, and nothing else in other classes accesses, or tries to access the arrays.
Actually, now that I think about it, I know it's not important. The program was originally structured. Making it look like OOP is just a way to get a guaranteed A for the lab,lol.